# Is it possible to do a vinyl fence with differing colors on each side?

Tags: fence, vinyl

So basically my neighbors want a plain white vinyl fence.  I think the two tone look is much nicer (white posts and rails but grey slat panels in the middle).

I've been looking for double sided slats where one side is white and one side is grey but can't seem to find anything... Seems like it would be a desirable product for more people than just me.

Do they make such a thing?  Or am I going to need to just try and paint the panels grey?  In that case, what's a good paint/technique to do this?

My neighbors already installed a section and it is blinding to look at, so I'm desperate for a solution.  Plain white is quite painful on the eyes, both aesthetically and physically painful from the sun's reflection.

Edit:
As a note, the plan was to split the cost with the neighbors.  I wanted grey, they wanted tan... We settled on white since it can go with either of our houses... However, the only thing I really agreed to so far was putting the fence on the property line... They went ahead and installed the fence without much more discussion or input... So I'm not technically on the hook for it cost-wise... Though I'll pay for my portion when I end up tying into it when I fence off our yard.

I can paint the inner panels grey to get the two tone look I want... Just not sure that would look very good.   I was hoping they had pre-made panels which are double sided.

Comment: put another fence against the neighbor's fence

Comment: I'm the fool who told them they could build it on the property line before I knew how awful the plain white was going to be (we had intentions of splitting the cost of the fence since we'll eventually be doing a vinyl fence around the entire perimeter of our property)

Comment: please post a picture of the fence if you can

Comment: Please tell my wife that she wants white around the front pasture that has a road down the center with 1 acre turnouts 4 on each side omg the cost and white.

Comment: @jsotola, image upload isn't working from mobile... Will try from a PC later

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vinyl takes paint. Scuff-sand it with a green 3M Scotchbrite pad to give it some roughness for the paint to engage.

Then prime with alkyd enamel.  Roller and brush it carefully so you don’t throw or drip any on their side. I would use white primer such as Rustoleum 7780 so if you have boo-boos with the primer they won’t be obvious. Then a latex/emulsion topcoat is fine.  Latex is much easier to clean up!